# some problems about my simple array code, this acts just like a very simple vector

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
class  my_int_array
private:
int num;
int *ptr;
public:
my_int_array(int n){
    num = n;
    int *ptr = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        ptr[i] = 0;
    }
}
my_int_array(int x[], int size){
    int *ptr = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        ptr[i] = x[i];
    }
}
my_int_array(my_int_array&other){
    int *ptr = new int[other.num];
    for (int i = 0; i < other.num; i++){
        ptr[i] = other.ptr[i];
    }
    num = other.num;
}
int size(){
    return num;
}
int at(int n){
    if (n > num - 1 || n < 0){
        cout << "out of range" << endl;
    }
    else{
        return ptr[n];
    }
}
my_int_array &operator=(const my_int_array&temp){
    int *ptr = new int[temp.num];
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.num; i++){
        ptr[i] = temp.ptr[i];
    }
    num = temp.num;
}
~my_int_array(){
    delete[] ptr;
}
};
int main(){
my_int_array arrry1(5);
cout << arrry1.size() << endl;
}
```

when I run this program, it can show 5,  but the .exe will then crash, and can someone help me find my errors in this code

what does it have:
1. create an empty array;
2. size() return the size of the array, and at() return the value of the certain index.
3. copy constructor and an assignment operator that make copies
4. when pass an array and the size of the array, this class shall copy that array to its elements.

if anyone can help, that would be great, as I am a new learner, any suggestion will be welcomed, thanks!

Comment: You redeclaring "int *ptr" in all of the constructors and not using the "int *ptr;" field declared in the private section. In the destructor you are deleting an uninitialized pointer which causes the crash. Remove the "int *" from the pointer declaration in the methods.

Comment: Your `operator=` doesn't return a value. Undefined behavior.  In addition, once you make the change to remove the `int*` from all your methods, your code is not exception safe.

Comment: @BrianWalker, I think you should promote your comment to an answer.

Comment: Thank a lot, it really works, I think there will be lots of things i should lean.

Comment: @BrianWalker - Please post your comment as an answer.  I posted the answer of the missing return value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A subtle error that you have is this (given that you fix the obvious error of declaring `ptr` each time):

```
my_int_array &operator=(const my_int_array&temp){
    ptr = new int[temp.num];
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.num; i++){
        ptr[i] = temp.ptr[i];
    }
    num = temp.num;
}
```

The problem is that your function is supposed to return a reference to a `my_int_array`, but it doesn't return anything.  This is `undefined behavior`, thus any code that assigns your objects will be faulty (possibly crash).

However, once you fix this, you have another issue, and that is that you didn't check for self-assignment.

To fix this, I will show you the simpler way of implementing `operator=`:

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
my_int_array &operator=(const my_int_array& rhs)
{
    my_int_array temp(rhs);
    std::swap(temp.ptr, ptr);
    std::swap(temp.num, num);
    return *this;
}
```

That's it. This works by using the copy constructor and destructor of `my_int_array` to your advantage, so it requires a perfectly working copy constructor and destructor for `my_int_array`.  Look up `copy and swap idiom`.